# Could not load file or assembly CMS.ApplicationDashboard, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Tags: kentico

Hello I am using kentico 8.2 version,

> Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.34209
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'CMS.ApplicationDashboard, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'CMS.ApplicationDashboard, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: You should provide more information about what changes you made to the project. Have you applied an upgrade or hotfix? You can see from the error that versions of your DLL are not consistent. Some of them are probably 8.0 and some are 8.2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Its the kentico web application upgraded from 8 to 8.2
how can I search for issue can you guide me..

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/9un0ja/9

Comment: above is error msg screenshot

Answer (score 0):

During your upgrade process, did you "load" the site after going from 8.0 to 8.1?  There are scripts that need to run after each hotfix that you apply, so you can't hotfix from 8.0 to 8.1, then straight to 8.2 without loading the site on 8.1 first.

If the above is the case, you may need to redo your upgrade, following kentico's steps.  Otherwise as noted, it seems your drivers are mixed up.  The LIB folder contains the drivers for the current version you are on, you can attempt to replace the BIN drivers in question with the ones in the LIB, but it's not highly recommended, as i'm not positive the lib is a 1 to 1 clone of the BIN.  Best to just redo the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, for pointing towards bin folder will check in that direction